# sort array of objects with pugjs/jade

Tags: arrays, sorting, pug

Can I sort an array of object with pugjs ? 
we can do `- array.sort()` in pug, but I want to sort something like this :

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.order - b.order;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It was simple if any one need it, you can do :

```
- array.sort(function(a, b) {return a. order - b.order;})
```